# Null pointer exception while retrieving data from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve user name from my firebase data base [here is what my database structure looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7wKn.png)

I have written this code and its showing error " `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference"`

Here's my code:

```
`public class MyAccount extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button mSetupButton;
private EditText mSetupName;
private EditText mSetupBio;
private ImageButton mSetupImageButton;

private String mPostKey=null;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_account);

    mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Profiles");
    mPostKey=getIntent().getExtras().getString("profile_id");

    mSetupName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.accountName);
    mSetupBio = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.accountBio);
    mSetupButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.accountButton);
    mSetupImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.accountImageButton);

    mDatabase.child(mPostKey).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String post_name = (String) dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue();
            mSetupName.setText(post_name);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

From your crash log, problem should be in the below line

```
mPostKey=getIntent().getExtras().getString("profile_id");
```

When opening the app from the background, because of app kill(killed from the background for some reason), it tried to create it from the stack, so for this case `getExtras()` will return null.

Solution:

1. Saved profile_id in onSaveInstanceState(). It will get call before your activity get killed.

   `@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
               super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
               //Save your keys here.
    }`
2. Check the `savedInstanceState` when onCreate, if available, get the profile_id from there.

Comment: facing this error Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()

Answer (score 0):

May be you are not passing anything in your intent, that is the reason why your getExtras is null & causing nullpointer. Add this check to avoid nullpointer.

```
if(getIntent.getExtras!=null){
   mPostKey=getIntent().getExtras().getString("profile_id");
}
```

Comment: i've tried 'if(getIntent.getExtras!=null){
   mPostKey=getIntent().getExtras().getString("profile_id");
}' but now im facing this error

Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()